# exception connected with SLF4J

Tags: java, hibernate

I can't creat sessionFactory. It throws an exception. Please help me to fix it:

```
public class HibernateUtil<ServiceRegistryBuilder> {

 private static final SessionFactory sessionFactory;

    static{
        try{
            sessionFactory = new AnnotationConfiguration().configure().buildSessionFactory();

        }catch (Throwable ex) {
            System.err.println("Session Factory could not be created." + ex);
            throw new ExceptionInInitializerError(ex);
        }   
    }

    public static SessionFactory getSessionFactory() {
        return sessionFactory;
    }
```

}

Comment: just check if apache logger jar is there in your classpath

Comment: I've added appropriate dependency in pom.xml and jar is under Maven Dependences

Comment: @Maria, Provide your pom.xml file and also the exception stacktrace in the question.